# Liang-Barsky Line Clipping Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, clipping

Is it possible to generalize Liang-Barsky Line Clipping Algorithm for n-dimensional space ?

Comment: Maybe try out Computer Graphics Stack Exchange
http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a little context for those reading, the [Liang-Barsky algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liang%E2%80%93Barsky_algorithm) determines the segment of an infinite straight line that intersects an axis-aligned rectangle, if any. And yes, it can be trivially extended to clipping lines against n-dimensional axis-aligned hyperrectangles pretty trivially.

Since we don't have LaTeX markup in this exchange, I'll use bold to represent n-dimensional vectors.

The parametric equation of our line is:

**x** = **p** + u * **d**

where **p** is some arbitrary point on the line and **d** is a vector in the direction of the line. u is our parameter. The output of this algorithm will be two values of u where the line enters & exits our hyperrectangle, respectively, or a good reason why we lack two such values. ;)

Our hyperrectangle can be defined by two vectors, **Least** and **Greatest**, expressing the least and greatest values covered along each axis. (n-dimensional analogs of the bottom-left and top-right corners)

Now we can define two vectors A and B:

**A** = **Greatest** - **p**,   **B** = **Least** - **p**

Now we look component by component...

```
u1 = NegativeInfinity;
u2 = PositiveInfinity;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   if(d[i] == 0)  // for floats you'll want an epsilon here.
   {
       // Our line is parallel to two of the hyperrectangle's sides.
       // A[i] < 0 means it passes "above" our rectangle,
       // B[i] > 0 means it passes "below"

       if(A[i] < 0 || B[i] > 0)
          return NO_INTERSECTION;
   }
   else
   {
      b = B[i]/d[i];
      a = A[i]/d[i];

      if(d[i] < 0)
      {
          // The line runs high to low along this axis.
          // it crosses the high side first (at a), then the low side (at b)
          u1 = max(u1, a);
          u2 = min(u2, b);
      }
      else
      {
          // The line runs low to high along this axis.
          // it crosses the low side first (at b), then the high side (at a)
          u1 = max(u1, b);
          u2 = min(u2, a);
      }

      if(u2 < u1)
          return NO_INTERSECTION;
   }
}
```

If we get to the bottom, then the line segment crosses our hyperrectangle from

**x1** = **p** + u1 * **d**

to

**x2** = **p** + u2 * **d**

and "kisses" the box along an edge or corner if u1 == u2, so there's only one point of intersection.

Comment: so if I wanted to define the clipping space in N-Dimensions I would want to define a point in N Space and a N dimensional vector. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @johnjohn yes, a line through n-dimensional space can be described by a single n-dimensional point somewhere on the line and an n-dimensional vector in the direction the line is travelling.